# php javascript ajax file upload not working

Tags: php, arrays, ajax

I'm using form data for uploading files code given below

```
var formData = new FormData();
/* Add the file */ 
formData.append("qqfile", file);
xhr.open("post", 'upload.php', true);
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream");
xhr.send(formData);  /* Send to server */
```

in upload.php my code is given below

```
$fileReader = fopen('php://input', "r");  
$fileWriter = fopen($this->_destination_file, "w+");  

while(true) {  
    $buffer = fgets($fileReader, 4096);
    if (strlen($buffer) == 0) {  
        fclose($fileReader);  
        fclose($fileWriter);  
        return true;  
    }  

    fwrite($fileWriter, $buffer);  
} 
return false;
```

when i'm trying to upload pdf file it's working perfectly, when I'm trying to upload .xls file,file is uploaded but when i open xls file getting non readable character.

Comment: could you change the `Content-Type` to `application/vnd.ms-excel` and test again?

Comment: Tried not working

Comment: could you do an md5 on the original file and the uploaded file? if they are not the same some content gets stripped while beeing uploaded

Comment: `Content-Type` should be `"multipart/form-data"`, please try that

Comment: Similar question asked here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10091154/php-ajax-file-upload

Comment: This is different

Comment: By the way i'm using this file uploader http://valums-file-uploader.github.io/file-uploader/

Comment: I have tried with Content-Type should be "multipart/form-data" not working